# `bedtools`: Intersecting/map into only one interval when there are multiple matches?

Tags: bedtools, interval

I have the following list of intervals

| Chr | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 0 | 5 |
| chr1 | 5 | 10 |
| chr1 | 10 | 15 |
| chr1 | 15 | 20 |
| chr1 | 20 | 25 |
| chr1 | 25 | 30 |

and the following CpGs I'd like to intersect with the intervals and aggregate the last two columns using sum.

| chr | start | end | end -1 | coverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| chr1 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| chr1 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 2 |
| chr1 | 10 | 12 | 11 | 2 |
| chr1 | 13 | 15 | 14 | 1 |
| chr1 | 16 | 18 | 17 | 2 |
| chr1 | 19 | 21 | 20 | 2 |
| chr1 | 22 | 24 | 23 | 2 |
| chr1 | 25 | 27 | 26 | 1 |

I ran `bedtools map -a cgis.bed -b s.bed -c 4 -o sum`, but when a CpG falls
across two regions, bedtools counts it in both. Here the 5 - 10 intervals should have only the second row of the CpG table: a sum of 2. However, since the second row spans 5, the 4 - 6 interval falls into both the 0 - 5 and the 5 - 10.

| chr | start | end | bedtools sum coverage | correct sum coverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 0 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| chr1 | 5 | 10 | 3 | 2 |
| chr1 | 10 | 15 | 3 | 3 |
| chr1 | 15 | 20 | 4 | 4 |
| chr1 | 20 | 25 | 4 | 2 |
| chr1 | 25 | 30 | 1 | 1 |

Can I use bedtools to place it in the lower interval only and not both? Intersects should be start inclusive, but end exclusive. This does work as I'd like if I reduce every end column element in the second CpG table by one.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer exactly? The second row of your CpG table really does overlap with two rows of your first table.

Comment: @bricoletc I want to pick the first of the overlapping regions, not both. If there are two the second one should not be counted. I think its a question of end-inclusive vs not. If every `end` in the CpGs table is reduced by one, I get the correct answer. I was wondering if its possible to get this correct answer without editing the input CpG file.